# Usage of TILDE inside a complex jQuery/CSS3 selector

Tags: css, jquery-selectors

I am struggling to understand a jQuery selector that I found inside a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/3/). The selector is:

```
'~.container, ~:has(.container)'
```

What is the meaning of the tilde?

- is it a kind of `:not` ?
- is it some sort of the partial match `~=` operator ?
- is it some variation of the "next siblings" selector?

I have searched a lot on the jQuery **and the W3C** sites, without finding such an usage of tilde. At least I did not recognize it.

Anybody could tell me where such usage of tilde is explained?

Comment: @Quentin - I assume your hasty reply hints at http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators - my question is: why there is no selector preceding the tilde? and where is such usage shown by the W3C precisely?

Comment: @davidkonrad - I assume your hasty reply hints at http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators - my question is: why there is no selector preceding the tilde? please try to answer my question, which is not what the other user was specifically trying to know.

Comment: @Quentin - glad to see your condescending comment has disappeared.

Comment: Lamers delete their own embarrassing misfired replies and anonymously downvote. That's great...

Comment: misfired? what u mean by that?

Comment: Guys above thought oneliners sufficed as answers. I helped them realize it wasn't so easy and they deleted their own comments. In the same minutes, two downvotes to this question arrived. Coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

Remember jQuery selector syntax is based on CSS selector syntax, and in CSS the tilde denotes "any of the following siblings." So

```
`~:has(.container)`
```

...finds any proceeding siblings that have the class `container`.

Comment: In my question I hinted this could be a variation of the 'next siblings' selector. The point is that all examples I can see on the W3C docs are 'X ~ Y'. In this case it seems there is no X. My questions are: 1) is there an implied X? Is that the current jquery selector? 3) Where is this special case illustrated? I appreciate your effort. Thank you.

Comment: @jbutler483 - I assume your hasty reply hints at w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators - my question is: why there is no selector preceding the tilde? and where is such usage shown by the W3C precisely?

Comment: No, i was going to show you this [implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors) - it refers to 'exactly', well, more  'includes' to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an awkward comment, so here goes:

Here's an example;

```
[att~=val]
```

and from the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors);

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a white
>   space-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val"
>   contains white space, it will never represent anything (since the
>   words are separated by spaces). If "val" is the empty string, it will
>   never represent anything either.

---

> The following selectors illustrate the differences between "=" and
>   "~=". The first selector will match, for example, the value "copyright
>   copyleft copyeditor" for the "rel" attribute. The second selector will
>   only match when the "href" attribute has the value
>   "http://www.w3.org/".

```
a[rel~="copyright"]
a[href="http://www.w3.org/"]
```

From reading this, I hope you could possibly understand the physical *use* for this. It allows you to select an 'includes' as such. Since there isn't really an '`:includes`' selector, a '`~`' can be used, quite commonly with a `:contains`.

---

I believe in your example,

```
'~.container, ~:has(.container)'
```

Is testing if you can 'find' a class `container` anywhere after this, or an element that 'includes' this `container` anywhere after your 'button clicked' element.

Comment: @jbutler484 - I appreciate your effort. Can you show me how rel~="copyright" maps to ~:has(.container) ? I see two issues here: 1) what is taking the place of 'rel' in the second example? 2) are we allowed to swap = with :has()? W3C uses the tilde only in association with = meaning 'string contains'. No other uses are mentioned. Have you ever used tilde in this way?

Comment: I've never actually *needed* this sort of implementation - I can only guess that it's used when you have no control over an external html stylesheet. But there are (i'm 99% sure) ways to completely *avoid* this awkward implementation, seeing as I've never felt the need to implement this in anyway. (I have, however, used the tilde as a sibling selector, but nothing ever like this before).

Comment: nice try, but still no cigar :-)  In my search before asking this question I have analyzed also this case (which is different from the ~= business) and here I miss the left operand. Please see my comment to the attempted answer from Utkanos. My guess is that jQuery is tweaking the CSS3 standard by using an implicit left operand, but I cannot find anywhere other examples of this practice.

Comment: @Muzietto: changing the fiddle doesn't seem to affect the output [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/Pm3cj/72/). I could simply be a mistake/issue with the original author.

Comment: Nope. I've tried that too. You can tell by clicking the links in your own fiddle that the behavior has definitely changed. There is some magic in that selector.